# Selecting an element within a parent element of another

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to find out how, I am able to select an element which is outside the element which has been clicked.

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
  <a href="javascript;" class="menu-toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-server"></i>
    <span>Server</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a>
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <span>Item one</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Within the code, I want to make it so when the user clicked the button, which will trigger the link, it will then display the "dropdown-menu", by adding the class "open" to list-item "nav-item dropdown".

I have more than one dropdown menu within the navigation too, so I cannot just simple select "dropdown-menu" and then make it visible, as it will make all of the dropdown menu's visible. So is there any way of doing this? I have tried to select the element, but it just selects them all, and I just cannot get my head around it.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$(this).next()` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/713/)

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
})
```

Comment: Just as a note instead of class you can use `fadeToggle` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/714/ or `slideToggle` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/715/

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla JS solution

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu-toggle').forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', event => {
       event.preventDefault();
       element.parentNode.querySelector('.dropdown-menu').classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hp1debw7/1/**

Comment: Seems a little confusing, but is still works, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the target parent using [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) methods, then just find the dropdown and add the class.

Example:

```
$('.menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).closest('.nav-item dropdown').find('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```